# PDF - combo box values change another field values

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe

I have a PDF form created.  One of the fields is a combo box with 3 values.  Based on the selection of these values in the combo box, I would like to change the value of another combo box or text field.

Combo box values =

```
Professional
Amateur
Novice
```

Results change the "other field"(which is going to be the title of the page)=

```
This is the professional cover sheet
This is the amateur cover sheet
This is the novice cover sheet
```

So to recap.  If I choose professional from the combo box, I want the text in the other field to change to "This is the professional cover sheet".  This text can either be in a text field or combo box or whatever you tell me will work.  This field is going to be placed as the title of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Bam!  Found the answer.  This works perfectly.

[AcrobatUsers - Click Here](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/change_another_field)

Answer (score 0):

This one is even better, gives more options/complexity.

[PlanetPDF - Click Here](http://www.planetpdf.com/planetpdf/pdfs/ExtAcrobatFormsJs_ch8.pdf)